# llvm passing loaded value to an external function

Tags: llvm

I am trying create a pass that will pass loaded value to an external function.
This is what i am doing

```
cpProfFunc = M.getOrInsertFunction("_Z6cpProfiiiiii",Type::getVoidTy(*Context),Type::getInt8tInt8PtrTy(*Context),NULL); 
if(isa<LoadInst>(&(*BI)) )     //next in block iterator
    std::vector<Value*> a1(1);              
LoadInst *CI = dyn_cast<LoadInst>(BI);
a1[0]=dyn_cast<ConstantExpr>(CI->getPointerOperand());
CallInst* newInst = CallInst::Create(cpProf,a1,"");
BB->getInstList().insert((Instruction*)CI, newInst);
```

This is giving me error.I dont know where i am wrong.Somebody,Please correct me.

Comment: "This is giving me an error" - what is that error?

Comment: Compilation error or runtime error?

Comment: Error at the time of running opt -load 
Error is:

a@ubuntu:~/Desktop$ ./myscript
llvm[0]: Compiling printFunc.cpp for Release+Asserts build (PIC)
llvm[0]: Linking Release+Asserts Loadable Module Ass1Pri.so
0  opt 0x0854449b
Stack dump:
0. Program arguments: opt -load /home/anshul/llvm/llvm-3.2/Release+Asserts/lib/Ass1Pri.so -anshul_insert 
1. Running pass 'test function exist' on module '<stdin>'.
./myscript: line 6: 10726 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) opt -load /home/anshul/llvm/llvm-3.2/Release+Asserts/lib/Ass1Pri.so -anshul_insert < a.bc > b1.bc
'main' function not found in module.

Answer (score 0):

You write that you receive the error:

```
Stack dump:
0.  Program arguments: opt -load /home/anshul/llvm/llvm-3.2/Release+Asserts/lib/Ass1Pri.so -anshul_insert
1.  Running pass 'test function exist' on module '<stdin>'.
./myscript: line 6: 10726 Segmentation fault (core dumped)
opt -load /home/anshul/llvm/llvm-3.2/Release+Asserts/lib/Ass1Pri.so -anshul_insert < a.bc > b1.bc
'main' function not found in module.
```

So it seems that a pass called "test function exist" is trying to actually run some bitcode file (probably invoking lli on it), but a `main` function is missing from that file.